# Android Facebook Login callback not working

Tags: java, android, facebook, authentication, callback

im trying to get access to user profile using facebook login. but im so confused with facebook tutorial. so far i think i've succeeded with logging in but was unable to get Profile. here's my code.

my fragment class:

```
public class FBLoginFragment extends Fragment {


private LoginButton loginButton;
private CallbackManager callbackManager;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fblogin, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setFragment(this);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");


    // Callback registration
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();

            // App code
            if(profile != null) System.out.println("login successful " + profile.getName());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code
            System.out.println("login cancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code
            System.out.println("login fail");
        }
    });


}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
}
```

my main activity code:

```
public class LoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private Fragment fragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
}
}
```

Comment: Are you getting a particular error or exception? Post more details about the error.

Comment: post your log-cat also to inspect.

Comment: i didnt get any error. just the callback not printing out what i want to print. and also profile returns null.

Comment: Have you tried adding breakpoints in your IDE to help see what is happening? To me it sounds like the login flow isn't being completed fully. You can check your own profile on Facebook.com to see if you have actually logged into the app.

Comment: Same issue. I successfully got token from callbackManager in onActvityResult(). But FacebookCallback<LoginResult> was never be called. Have you solve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

In your Manifest file, the activity which contains the Facebook login button may have noHistory attribute like the following:

```
 <activity
  ...
  android:noHistory="true"
  ...  >
```

Removing it will solve your problem.

Comment: This is the correct answer. It is criminal to ask a question and then not mark an answer as correct. Thanks Mohammed.